# Highcharts3.0.2 adapter and plugin for ExtJS3.2

Tags: extjs, highcharts

Can someone tell me Highcharts3.0.2 adapter and plugin for ExtJS3.2  the download address?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this?
Highcharts 3.0.2
http://www.highcharts.com/downloads/zips/Highcharts-3.0.2.zip 
ExtJS
http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/ext-4.2.1-gpl.zip

Comment: I the front end of the framework is based on extjs3.2,now I need to introduce Highcharts 3.0.2 to develop,but Highcharts no official wrapper for extJS, I need some help plug-in.

Comment: http://joekuan.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/highcharts-adapter-for-ext-js-with-animation-support/ ?